# After webpack build (via gulp) - Toggle JS script stops binding to all toggles

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, babel-loader

After I run webpack and transpile + combine all (6) of my js files, the custom toggle function I made stops working on all the toggles.
Toggles that are html `<button>` elements work fine, but the toggles that are `<a>` anchor tags stop working.

If I stop referencing the bundle.js in my html and reference the separate js files again, things work as they did (and as expected).

Webpack seems to run fine, without any errors. there are no console errors present in the browser.

This is a vanilla JS project, no react or vue or other front-end frameworks are used.

There are some bootstrap classes still in the html, but bootstrap has been removed and those classes are just remnants for now.

The elements involved:

Button element that still works as a toggle

```
<button class="navbar-toggler hidden-md-min" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" id="mobileNavToggle" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

Anchor element that stops working for some reason

```
<a id="megaMenuThree"
  href="#"
  data-toggle="dropdown"
  aria-haspopup="true"
  aria-expanded="false"
  class="nav-link dropdown-toggle">Toggle anchor
</a>
```

The JS involved

```
// init dropdowns is called on main.js after everthing loads
export const initDropdowns = () => document.querySelectorAll('[data-toggle~=dropdown]').forEach(setupDropdown);

const setupDropdown = (dropdownToggle) => {
  dropdownToggle.setAttribute('aria-haspopup', 'true');
  dropdownToggle.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');

  let dropdownMenu = dropdownToggle.parentNode.querySelector('.dropdown-menu');

  dropdownMenu.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');

  dropdownToggle.onclick = (evt) => {
    console.log("click happened!");
    evt.preventDefault();
    toggleDropdown(dropdownToggle, dropdownMenu);
  };

  // Toggle needs to close menu when a menu-item is clicked or when something outside the menu is clicked**
  dropdownAutoClose(dropdownToggle);
};
```

The console log included in the onclick block fires for the buttons, but nothing on the anchors, which make it seem like it isn't binding (or something).

and my webpack config just in case

```
const path  = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './source/js/main.js',
  mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {extensions: ['.js']},
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/js'),
  },
  devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

The only difference I can think of is that one element is a button (which works after webpack build) and the other is an anchor (which doesn't work  after webpack build for some reason).

I've removed the babel transpilation from the webpack config just to make sure it isn't that, the issue persists.
When using the plain js files not bundled by webpack, things work fine.

Does anyone have any idea why this would happen?
I've googled and tried for hours to figure out what the issue is.

Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Got the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after much googling and research and wondering why no one else has experienced this kind of thing, I found a solution that worked for me.

I changed this

```
  dropdownToggle.onclick = (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    toggleDropdown(dropdownToggle, dropdownMenu);
  };
```

to this

```
dropdownToggle.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  toggleDropdown(dropdownToggle, dropdownMenu);
});
```

Not sure why the former didn't work after being `webpacked`, but this solved my issue. It must be something to do with the `eventlistener` and how it got applied.

Still happy to hear an explanation if anyone has one.

Comment: I've got the same issue but addEventListerner didn't fix it for me.
In browser Inspector mode I can literally see the toggle happing.

Comment: BUT....
The new class doesn't override the current class.
display:none => display:flex
It is as if the specificity of the current class is higher than the new class.
OR because they're on the same level => first come first serve.
I literally had to convert to an if-else on the getByID.

Comment: So it definitely has to do with the order of the classes
if you remove all the classes on the element and toggle classList with changed order it sort of works. Still bugs out on me.